# Rails ActiveRecord has_many through not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, foreign-keys, schema

I have a rails app where users have children. So I had two models: :users and :children.

I used to have a one-to-many relationship (has_many / belongs_to), but I wanted to open it up to a many-to-many relationship where I could store variables about the relationship. So I changed the relationship to a "has_many through" relationship. I created a table called :relationships. A small caveat: I want the foreign_key for user to be :parent_id. Here is how I have them set up:

Schema:

```
create_table "relationships", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "child_id"
    t.integer  "parent_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
.
.
.

create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                                  :null => false
    t.datetime "created_at",                             :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                             :null => false
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
.
.
.

create_table "children", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name",                :null => false
    t.integer  "parent_id",           :null => false
    t.datetime "created_at",          :null => false
.
.
.
```

Class Definitions:

user.rb:

```
has_many :relationships, foreign_key: "parent_id"
has_many :children, :through => :relationships, foreign_key: "parent_id"
```

child.rb:

```
has_many :relationships, foreign_key: "child_id"
has_many :parents, :through => :relationships
```

relationship.rb:

```
belongs_to :parent, class_name: "User", :foreign_key => :parent_id
belongs_to :child, class_name: "Child", :foreign_key => :child_id
```

Now when I choose a specific user and try to get user.children, I get [] in response. If I try to add new children, it doesn't work either. I can define the parent and the child, but when it tries to save, It cannot associate the two. It doesn't see the parent, so I get the error:

***ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::Error: ERROR:  null value in column "parent_id" violates not-null constraint***

If I switch the Class definitions back to a one-to-many setup, it accesses the children just fine. I don't understand what the problem is. Any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you building the relationship? `@user.children` works for me with the given example when I create the relationship as follows:

```
@user.relationships.build(child_id: ...)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not change anything for me. It is still not associating the users and children.

Comment: Comment for the edit: Well I tried this as well. It will go through without giving me any errors, but a child doesn't actually get written. I tried:

'user.relationships.build(child_id: 200)'

but I couldn't call it back when attempting:

'user.children.find(200).inspect'

Comment: You need to `.save` the relationship. or more directly: @user.relationships.create(child_id: ...).

Comment: No change. It is not just about writing new children. It should be able to read the children that were in the db before I made this change, but it is not doing that either. It seems the association is broken, somehow.

Comment: It will not be able to associate users with children already in the database without creating relationships between them first. the "has_many ... :through => " association cannot make use of the parent_id column in your user model -- it only uses the relationship table.

Comment: With a "user" defined, I was able to do this:

new_child = Child.create(name: ...)
user.relationships.create(child_id: new_child.id, parent_id: user.id ...)

Answer (score -1):

in children table `parent_id` should be allowed to take null if you want create children as nested attributes.

Change

```
create_table "children", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "name",                :null => false
  t.integer  "parent_id",           :null => false
  t.datetime "created_at",          :null => false
end
```

To

```
   create_table "children", :force => true do |t|
      t.string   "name",                :null => false
      t.integer  "parent_id"
      t.datetime "created_at",          :null => false
    end
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't solve the real problem. It is still not able to connect children and parents (or users). All that did was allow it to store a child without a parent, which is not what I want.